Ubuntu 24.04 losing internet connection and microphone function
I've been facing this problem since I upgraded my Mac Mini late 2012 to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. It happens with all versions of this new Linux update, even with the last release of Linux Mint. The problem happens a lot while I'm on a "Google Meet" meeting, after some time in it, the internet connection just hangs off (but only on the computer) and after being connected again, the microphone, for some reason, just stops working, and I have to leave the meeting because no one can hear me anymore. The microphone only starts working again after a computer's restart.
It's horrible because I've been resetting this computer with a lot of different distros based on that Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, (like Linux Mint), and in all of them I have to face this problem.
